# php fgets, fwrite and newline

Tags: php, newline, fwrite, fgets

Using php fgets function , I am reading from one file, file "A" which is in a particular format and I am writing to another file, file "B" in a particular format using fwrite. 
However, no matter what new lines or line breakers I put, some characters keep being misplaced.
Below is the format I wish to see in the new file, file B:

```
ICCID,IMSI,KI,ESN,PIN1,PUK1,PIN2,PUK2,IMSI2,KI2,ACC_NBR,NAI_USERNAME,NAI_PASS
8926003010422000616F,,,645030142200061,2064,16002217,4029,34594354,,,,,
8926003010422000624F,,,645030142200062,8678,91445678,5351,06417774,,,,,
8926003010422000632F,,,645030142200063,0356,51052167,6976,27210792,,,,,
8926003010422000640F,,,645030142200064,5504,38104570,4917,61385706,,,,,
8926003010422000657F,,,645030142200065,7158,23625228,2726,13487033,,,,,
8926003010422000665F,,,645030142200066,3922,52488665,6014,33705660,,,,,
```

BUT below is exactly what I am getting:

```
ICCID,IMSI,KI,ESN,PIN1,PUK1,PIN2,PUK2,IMSI2,KI2,ACC_NBR,NAI_USERNAME,NAI_PASS
8926003010422000608F,,,645030142200060,3741,26564507,7283,13507659
,,,,,8926003010422000616F,,,645030142200061,2064,16002217,4029,34594354
,,,,,8926003010422000624F,,,645030142200062,8678,91445678,5351,06417774
,,,,,8926003010422000632F,,,645030142200063,0356,51052167,6976,27210792
,,,,,8926003010422000640F,,,645030142200064,5504,38104570,4917,61385706
,,,,,8926003010422000657F,,,645030142200065,7158,23625228,2726,13487033
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

you will notice the characters `,,,,,` get put at the start of a line rather than the end where I want them to be. Notice also the last line gets to be `,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,`. Not needed at all.

Below is the code that reads and writes. Needing someone to help me sort out this.

```
    $headStockin= "ICCID,IMSI,KI,ESN,PIN1,PUK1,PIN2,PUK2,IMSI2,KI2,ACC_NBR,NAI_USERNAME,NAI_PASSWORD"."\r\n";
    $file = fopen($inputFile, "r");  // reading input file
    $myStockinfile = fopen($inputFile."_StockIn.txt", "wb") or die("Unable to create/open a file!"); 
    fwrite($myStockinfile, $headStockin);
    $thr=",,,";
    $one=",";
    $fiv=",,,,,";

    $lineNo = 0;
    $startLine = 21;

    while(!feof($file)){
        $lineNo++;
        $line = fgets($file);

        if ($lineNo >= $startLine) {
            $result = explode(" ", $line);
            $in= $result[2].$thr.$result[1].$one.$result[3].$one.$result[5].$one.$result[4].$one.$result[6].$fiv;
            echo $in;   //to see output on html
            fwrite($myStockinfile,$in);
        }

    }
    fclose($file);
    fclose($myStockinfile);

}



INPUT FILE BELOW

    *
********************************************************************************
* HEADER DESCRIPTION
********************************************************************************
*
Quantity:   5000
*
********************************************************************************
* INPUT VARIABLES
********************************************************************************
*
var_in_list:
IMSI:   645030142200060
Ser_Nb: 8926003010422000608F
*
********************************************************************************
* OUTPUT VARIABLES
********************************************************************************
*
var_out:MSISDN/IMSI/ICCID/PIN1/PIN2/PUK1/PUK2
+260950605404 645030142200060 8926003010422000608F 3741 7283 26564507 13507659
+260950605411 645030142200061 8926003010422000616F 2064 4029 16002217 34594354
+260950605412 645030142200062 8926003010422000624F 8678 5351 91445678 06417774
+260950605416 645030142200063 8926003010422000632F 0356 6976 51052167 27210792
+260950605418 645030142200064 8926003010422000640F 5504 4917 38104570 61385706
+260950605421 645030142200065 8926003010422000657F 7158 2726 23625228 13487033
```

Comment: Your file is comma-separated, but you use `explode(" ", $line)`, which uses space as the column delimiter.

Comment: Looks like it was just a typo, `explode(" ", $line)` should be `explode(",", $line)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The misplaced commas are because `fgets()` returns a string that includes the newline at the end. So `$fesult[6]` has a newline at the end, so `$fiv` gets put onto the next line. The solution is to trim the input before exploding, and then write a newline in your output.

The extra line is because you're testing for EOF before reading the line. `feof()` isn't detected until *after* you read the end of the file.

So change your loop to:

```
while ($line = fgets($file)) {
    $lineNo++;
    if ($lineNo < 21) { // Skip first 20 lines
        continue;
    }
    $line = rtrim($line);
    $result = explode(" ", $line);
    $in= $result[2].$thr.$result[1].$one.$result[3].$one.$result[5].$one.$result[4].$one.$result[6].$fiv.PHP_EOL;
    echo $in;
    fwrite($myStockinfile, $in);
}
```

Comment: I explode with "  " because the original file is delimetered by " " .

Comment: Below is the original file:
IMSI: 645030142200060
Ser_Nb: 8926003010422000608F
*
********************************************************************************
* OUTPUT VARIABLES
********************************************************************************
*
var_out:MSISDN/IMSI/ICCID/PIN1/PIN2/PUK1/PUK2
+260950605404 645030142200060 8926003010422000608F 3741 7283 26564507 13507659
+260950605411 645030142200061 8926003010422000616F 2064 4029 16002217 34594354
+260950605412 645030142200062 8926003010422000624F 8678 5351 91445678 06417774

Comment: Please update the question with the input file. Use the `{}` tool in the SO editor to mark it as code, so it will be displayed literally.

Comment: Suddenly the "Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource"  error from fwrite, didnt have it before.

Comment: After I changed the code to your proposed i get Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: I had a typo, I had lowercase `s` in `myStockinfile`.

Comment: briliant, we I think we are almost there, I just need to put back the point, I want the fgets to start reading from line 20. A second, I will revert

Comment: Thank you very much Barmar. You a life saver, a start. I can now sleep. May come back tomorrow with a fresh query :-)